# JSF: h commandlink action is opening a new pop-up of the same page instead of calling the bean method

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2, commandlink

I had a look at this question but I could not fully understand where the issue is

[commandLink/commandButton/ajax backing bean action/listener method not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked)

My issue is that when I click on the link, it opens up a new pop up window but of the same page. Of course, nothing is rendered there.

This is the form:

```xml
<h:form id="PipelineOpportunities">
    <h:dataTable var="pipelineOppor"
                 value="#{my.pipeLineList}"
                 id="pipleLineTable"
                 binding="#{myBean.pipleLineTable}">
        <td>
            <h:column>
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                    onclick="selectedPipeOpportunities(this, '#{pipelineOppor.pipelineOpportunityID}');"
                    value="#{pipelineOppor.pipelineOpportunityID}">
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </h:column>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{pipelineOppor.topic}" />
            </h:column>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{pipelineOppor.createdOn}" />
                <f:attribute name="float" value="left"/>
            </h:column>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:column>
                <h:commandLink value="#{myBean.productSizeMap[pipelineOppor.pipelineOpportunityID]}" action="#{myBean.loadMyMethod}" >
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:column>
        </td>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This is what I have declared in my bean

```
private Map opportunityProductMap;
private Map productSizeMap;
private HtmlDataTable pipleLineTable;
private Map selectedIds = new HashMap();
public String loadMyMethod() {}
```

After the page is rendered and I click on any of the links, it opens up a new pop up instead of hitting the server. The new pop up is the same as the parent page without the styling or the data. Just plain text

So my question is what must I do to get the managed bean's method to get invoked

Comment: Is any error given in the javascript console? press F12 to open the console and then click on the link again.

Comment: what is the code of #{myBean.loadMyMethod} ??

Comment: There's no error showing. There's nothing inside the loadMyMethod method. I've just put a print statement to check if the control is coming into the method.

Comment: and please format and clean-up your code examples and make it an [mcve]. Hard to read (and with lots of 'errors')

Comment: I've formatted the form markup code. hope it helps

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Try another browser/machine to exclude malware from being the cause.